# Get all data, but omit Columns that are auto-increment

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm struggling to create a query that will return all information from a table (like SELECT *), but I would like to omit the column(s) that are auto-incremental.

Reason is, I'm displaying all data (using SELECT *, because I don't always know what columns are available) in a grid-view control, then I open the table up to allow for updates to be carried out. However this also opens up the column(s) that are assigned as auto-incremental for edit and prevents the update query from working.

So far I found the 'sys.columns.is_identity' table which seems it would help in some fashion, I'm just not sure how I could use this with a dynamic SELECT. 
It should be noted that the columns are not always known, hence I use SELECT * to retrieve the initial required data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, only way to do this is using `sys.columns` and dynamic query

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(8000)

SET @col_list = (SELECT ',' + Quotename(c.NAME)
                 FROM   sys.columns c
                        JOIN sys.objects o
                          ON c.object_id = o.object_id
                 WHERE  o.NAME = 'table_name'
                        AND is_identity <> 1
                 ORDER  BY column_id
                 FOR xml path(''))
SET @col_list = Stuff(@col_list, 1, 1, '')

EXEC('select '+@col_list +' from yourtable')
```